# 1.9 - Can't upload image

Tags: javascript, upload

I have a trouble with upload images in Magento backend. I think there is a problem with

```
<?php echo $this->getJsObjectName() ?>
```

in `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/media/uploader.html`. I have an JS errors. This scirpt:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[

var maxUploadFileSizeInBytes = <?php echo $this->getDataMaxSizeInBytes() ?>;
var maxUploadFileSize = '<?php echo $this->getDataMaxSize() ?>';

<?php echo $this->getJsObjectName() ?> = new Flex.Uploader('<?php echo $this->getHtmlId() ?>', '<?php echo $this->getUploaderUrl('media/uploader.swf') ?>', <?php echo $this->getConfigJson() ?>);

if (varienGlobalEvents) {
    varienGlobalEvents.attachEventHandler('tabChangeBefore', <?php echo $this->getJsObjectName() ?>.onContainerHideBefore);
}

//]]>
</script>
```

on my browser looks:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[

var maxUploadFileSizeInBytes = ;
var maxUploadFileSize = '';

 = new Flex.Uploader('id_be78c0de320409a822bfb385331b6473_Uploader', '', );

if (varienGlobalEvents) {
    varienGlobalEvents.attachEventHandler('tabChangeBefore', .onContainerHideBefore);
}

//]]>
</script>
```

Do you have any ideas what's wrong is this code?

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 1.9.3 they removed flash player buttons, so no need to worry about flash player anymore. If you are using 1.9.2, try apply the [SUPEE-8788](https://magento.com/security/patches/supee-8788) patch, Also check this [post](https://community.magento.com/t5/Security-Patches/SUPEE-8788-Solutions-to-Different-Problems/td-p/52572). If you already have the patch, hope bellow steps will be helpfull.

1- Check browser console for any javascript errors.

2- inspect the 'Browse/Upload' button area to check any issues.

3- Delete all files inside the folder `skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/`

4- Make sure below js were included, you can view source in browser.

```
lib/uploader/flow.min.js
lib/uploader/fusty-flow.js
lib/uploader/fusty-flow-factory.js 
mage/adminhtml/uploader/instance.js
```

5- Also make sure these js files not included, if exist just remove.

```
lib/flex.js
lib/FABridge.js
mage/adminhtml/flexuploader.js
```